# systemd starts a service which has ordering after a disabled service

Tags: systemd, systemctl, systemd-unit

service B unit configuration (it is an oneshot service):

```
[Unit]
Description=Service B
After=serviceA.service
```

service A is disabled by default (it is a simple service)

```
● serviceA.service - service A
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/serviceA.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

I would expect service B to not start until service A is started because of the ordering requirement. What I am observing is that service B starts without waiting for service A when machine is booted up. Can anyone explain this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start `serviceB.service` only if `serviceA.service` is started (and it's running) then you should add: `Requisite` to your `serviceB.service`.

From `man systemd.unit`:

> Requisite=
>
> Similar to Requires=. However, if the units listed here are not started already, they will not be started and the starting of this
> unit will fail immediately.  Requisite=
> does not imply an ordering dependency, even if both units are started in the same transaction. Hence this setting should usually
> be combined with After=, to ensure this unit
> is not started before the other unit.

**serviceB.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Service B
After=serviceA.service
Requisite=serviceA.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/user/somescript.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So for example, if you don't enable `serviceA.service` or this one it's not running when the `serviceB.service` wants to run then you should get a message like this in the `serviceB.service` logs:

```
A dependency job for serviceB.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
```